# padlock with 9 in middle

Tags: windows, windows-vista

On a Dell Vista computer keyboard, the padlock with a 9 in the middle has appeared. The google sites I visited all say it's a number lock but I can't get it to release and the keyboard appears frozen. Now what?

[image]

Comment: You are going to have to describe the problem in more detail, a screenshot, would provide the required information.

Answer (score 1):

That means Numlock is on, you should have a key labeled <kbd>NumLock</kbd> it toggles the indicator on and off.

Try restarting the PC, see if anything changes, if you cannot restart the pc using normal ways, do a hard shutdown, do this by pressing and holding the power button in until it shuts down.

Another reason it could be stuck is the keyboard is defective, Power down the PC and try another keyboard if you have one.

Comment: You might also find you have to press an "Fn" key plus a key on your keyboard with the same padlock icon - this should toggle the light on/off as required.